# Unable to get time value with date in d3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm new to D3.js. I have two problem while creating line chart in D3.js.

One is, I have tried to create line chart in D3.js using the following input values. In my output graph X-axis, I didn't get the time along with date which is present in the input file. I didn't understand how do date parsing into some format happening while creating graph. I don't know how to parse the date into some format to get date with time in my graph x-axis.

file name : lne1-data.csv

```
date,value
1-May-12 7:30,58.13
30-Apr-12 8:30,53.98
27-Apr-12 9:10,67.00
26-Apr-12 10:20,89.70
25-Apr-12 11:00,99.00
24-Apr-12 12:30,130.28
23-Apr-12 13:20,166.70
20-Apr-12 14:40,234.98
19-Apr-12 15:10,345.44
```

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->    
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
//var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 70, left: 50},  
  width = 1600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y %H:%M").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
//var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
  //  .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(6)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(7);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("lne1-data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));



    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>
```

My output graph:

[image]

Instead of the above graph, I need a graph which should have date with time in X-axis. what do i need to do to get time?

Another one is, I need to draw a vertical line to make two seperate parts like pre cutover, post cutover in that graph for particular date.

Eg. I need a vertical line on the date "2012-Apr-25 11:00"

How do I solve this problems? Can anyone help me to solve these problem please?

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure because i cannot test it now, but have you tried `var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` and `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return format(d.date); }));` ?

Comment: Hi Yoplaboom, Thanks for reply. I tried that method. I get only the date. I didn't get time with that date. It was "00:00" in the time place. In My code, Did I do anything wrongly or Is there any other way to get time?

Comment: @KarthickS i think in time scale, time cannot be displayed even when you pass tickValues some expert will definitely find a way :)